# how to create multiple dynamic block entries from a list pulled from a map

Tags: terraform, f5

i have varible which is a map

```
variable ltm-datagroups = {
  "0" = {
    datagroup_name      = "abc"
    datagroup_type      = "ip"
    datagroup_addresses = ["10.0.0.0/8", "172.16.1.0/24"]
  }
  "1" = {
    datagroup_name      = "def"
    datagroup_type      = "ip"
    datagroup_addresses = ""
  }
}
```

i pass this map to a module, which looks up the value for "datagroup_addresses". from that i want to create multiple entries, based on length of the list.

```
resource "bigip_ltm_datagroup" "datagroup" {
  for_each = var.ltm-datagroups
  name     = lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_name")
  type     = lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_type")
  dynamic "record" {
    for_each = lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_addresses") != "" ? ["${length(lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_addresses"))}"] : []
    content {
      name = lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_addresses")
    }
  }
}
```

this is the error i see

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on modules/ltm-datagroup/main.tf line 8, in resource "bigip_ltm_datagroup" "datagroup":
   8:   name = lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_addresses")
    |----------------
    | each.key is "0"
    | var.ltm-datagroups is object with 2 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on modules/ltm-datagroup/main.tf line 8, in resource "bigip_ltm_datagroup" "datagroup":
   8:   name = lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_addresses")
    |----------------
    | each.key is "1"
    | var.ltm-datagroups is object with 2 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "name": string required.
```

i am stuck on the last part. how to run the dynamic block multiple times? while iterating through the entries in the list?

Comment: what is `var.ltm-datagroups`? Do you get any errors? If yes, what are these?

Comment: i messed up while copying data. the variable is ltm-datagroups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand your desired outcome, but if you want to create `record` dynamically, then it should be:

```
  dynamic "record" {
    for_each = lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_addresses") != "" ? toset(lookup(var.ltm-datagroups[each.key], "datagroup_addresses")) : []
    content {
      name = record.value
    }
  }
```